# SVN to Git import problem using "git svn clone"

Tags: svn, git, version-control

When trying to import my SVN repo in Git, using the following command:

`git svn clone -s https://xx.xx.xx.xxx/repo/iphone/project ./project`

It runs for a long while and then finally craps out with the following error:

`RA layer request failed: REPORT of '/repo/!svn/vcc/default': SSL negotiation failed: SSL error: parse tlsext (https://xx.xx.xx.xxx) at /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5091`

Has anyone ever seen this problem?

Comment: Can you view the svn repo with a web browser?

Comment: @Rudi yes, I am able to view the repo with a browser, so the connection does get established.  It just seems to die out after a while!  This could be because our server is hosted by a member on my team and his connection is sketchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to figure this out.  I ended up doing an `svnsync` to move the entire repository down locally, and then from there I would run:

```
git svn clone -s file:///pathtolocal/repo/iphone/project ./project
```

My thought is that the SSL connection would die out after running for a while and mess up the clone.

A more detailed explanation with step-by-step instructions is found here on our blog:
[Permanent SVN to Git Transition](http://blog.terminaleleven.com/post/6370176211/permanent-svn-to-git-transition)

Now we are setup with pure Git happiness.

Comment: The linked blog post seems to have disappeared, it would be useful to add the actual details to this post..

Comment: @castaway I updated the blog link, sorry about that. Too long a post to put here in SO!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
git svn clone -s http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/repo/iphone/project ./project
```

Comment: No I can't do normal http because the SVN server is SSL access only, unfortunately.