# Unknown protocol error when using git-svn over HTTPS through a proxy server

Tags: git, svn, ssl, git-svn

I've been encountering some problems attempting to access a Subversion repository via HTTPS using git-svn.

When I type `git svn init --username=<my username> --trunk=https://<host>/<project>/trunk`, I get the following error message:

```
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/<project>/trunk':
PROPFIND of '/<project>/trunk': SSL negotiation failed: SSL error: unknown
protocol (https://<host>) at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn
line 2299
```

A couple of other points to note:

1. I'm using msysgit 1.7.9.0 on Windows 7 x64. I also have the Subversion 1.7.1 command line client and TortoiseSVN 1.7.1 installed.
2. I am connecting through a proxy server, which I have specified through both the HTTP_PROXY environment variable and `git config http.proxy`.
3. I am able to clone Github repositories over HTTPS on the same machine without problems.
4. The plain Subversion client checks out the same project without problems. I have also been able to clone it successfully with Mercurial and hgsubversion, although it did fail to recognise the server's SSL certificate, so I had to specify it explicitly in my mercurial.ini file. Because of this, I am using `git config http.sslVerify=false`. However, this does not make any difference.
5. One-way workarounds such as using svnsync (as e.g. suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838834/svn-to-git-import-problem-using-git-svn-clone)) are not an option.

Anything else that I haven't tried?

Comment: Can you first verify that you can check out that project with plain subversion client, to rule out any problem with subversion itself?

Comment: I have already done so -- Subversion client checks out the project without problems.

Comment: James, `openssl s_client -connect host:443` please for sake

Comment: `CONNECTED(00000003)
3132:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:567:`

Comment: Could you try to clone another svn repo? Try to find any project which stores source under svn, e.g. https://vegastrike.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/vegastrike/trunk/ (but it is svn 1.6, maybe you would be luckier to find svn 1.7 somewhere).

Comment: That gives the same error message. However, vanilla Subversion checks it out without problems.

Comment: Hm... Weird. You said you are using an http proxy. It is the next suspect. Could you test without proxy? Is is possible what you have some malicious software like virus or antivirus which intercepts the https traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally discovered how to get it to work. The answer came from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/msysgit/8U1yDnZo2bc).

When you're connecting to a Subversion server through a proxy, git-svn doesn't use the proxy settings in .gitconfig, nor does it use the settings you configure in TortoiseSVN. Instead, it looks in the `[global]` section of `%USERPROFILE%\.subversion\servers`.

Adding our proxy server settings to this file allowed me to connect to an external Subversion server.

Answer (score 9):

To expand a little bit on the other two answers (and explain why you're seeing what you're seeing), `git svn` (as part of msysgit) is built against svn 1.4.6:

```
C:\> git svn --version
git-svn version 1.7.7.1.msysgit.0 (svn 1.4.6)
```

Note that 1.4.6 is...  well... old.  (And [hasn't even been supported since 1.6 was released](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#svn-1.4-deprecation) in 2009.)

msysgit's `git-svn` is **not** using your subversion install - so being able to checkout using your installed `svn` is (unfortunately) not indicative of the problem.

There are [some bug reports](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=253) about upgrading to a newer subversion for msysgit, but it appears that those have not yet materialized.

Have you tried cygwin's `git-svn`?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but it might be possible to simply replace the libsvn dlls with those from a newer version of svn.  I don't have an easily accessible Windows machine to test it out however.

Comment: I have tried cygwin's git-svn. Unfortunately, it gives almost the same error, with the exception that it says OPTIONS rather than PROPFIND.

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting (SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) is easy to google. E.g. [here](http://www.nurdletech.com/https.html) or [here](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html) Looks like you have the https or dns servers misconfigured and nothing to do with git.

Comment: This does not explain why I was able to connect successfully using both vanilla Subversion and Mercurial/hgsubversion. The only thing your links suggest that I could follow through is "The Destination Site Does Not Like the Cipher" -- however, how can I specify a different cipher using git-svn? Also, I do not have access to the server to tweak the https or DNS settings.

Answer (score 1):

Offering a slightly less terse answer, kan [is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896518/517815). The reason why you are seeing this is your upstream repository isn't properly configured for SVN+HTTPS. This can be due to a misconfiguration at the server end, or it can be due to a difference in the SVN protocol being served versus what your client expects.

The errata provides the correct debugging scenarios for this problem. If you have control over the SVN repository in question, please ensure [its HTTPS configuration is working properly](https://csoft.net/docs/svndav.html.en) to proceed using this as your upstream repository. If you wish to change the protocol or URL being used to further troubleshoot the connection (for example, to try over HTTP or SSH), [here's the guide you'll need](http://www.sanityinc.com/articles/relocating-git-svn-repositories).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer has the same problem: it does not explain (a) why vanilla Subversion works fine and Mercurial/hgsubversion can be made to work fine too, and (b) why an SVN repository on SourceForge also fails. I'm beginning to think this is more likely to be a proxy server issue.